# Data constructor and working with maybe

Tags: haskell

The first function "encode" works and takes Lists of Bool statements and makes them into Is and Os. In the function "decode" i am supposed to decode the Is and Os again into True and False. In the decode function i am having trouble with checking if there are any elements that are not in data Bit to which the programm is supposed to respond with Nothing.

In the decode otherwise guard Just (l xs) does not give me "Just [[False],[False],[True]]" for "decode [O,O,I]" It leaves out the first Bit "Just [False],[True]" and I do  not know why that is.

```
module Blueprint where
import Prelude
import Data.List
import Data.Maybe

data Bit = O | I  deriving (Eq, Show)

encode :: [[Bool]] -> [Bit]
encode [] = []
encode (x:xs) |x==[True]  = I : encode xs
          |otherwise  = O : encode xs

l :: [Bit] -> [[Bool]]
l [] = []
l (x:xs) |x==I =[True] : l xs
         |x==O =[False]: l xs

decode :: [Bit] -> Maybe [[Bool]]
decode xs |{-if anything is in the list that is not in data Bit-} = Nothing
              |otherwise = Just (l xs)
```

Comment: you're calling `l` on the tail of the list

Comment: Why are you using `[Bool]` instead of `Bool`?

Comment: Can you give an example of an input to `decode` which should return `Nothing`?

Comment: @jberryman thx this fixed the second problem. `decode xs = Just (l xs)`

Comment: @ErikR [I,O,abc,I] should return Nothing. Anything that is not [I,O...] should return Nothing.

Comment: @HornsUp - but `decode` needs a list of Bit values, and `abc` is (presumably) not a Bit, so you couldn't even construct that list in the first place. Now if `decode` operateed on a list of String values, I could see where it could return Nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition

```
data Bit = O | I
```

enforces that `[Bit]` can only have `I/O`.  Perhaps you just need to handle empty list case?  Also, the representation of single true/false values as singleton lists is strange.  Why not just use `Bool`?

I would simplify it as

```
encodeBit O = False
encodeBit I = True

decodeBit False = O
decodeBit True = I

> map encodeBit [O,O,I]
[False,False,True]

> map decodeBit it
[O,O,I]
```